# Can c# send an email to an address that contains french characters?

Tags: c#, email, exception, internationalization

I have a c# application that uses the standard `MailMessage` and `SmtpClient` classes to send emails.  This works fine and great.  However, we have recently uploaded data from a government agency and some of the email addresses contain french characters.  eg Hélène@somedomain.com

When I send an email to the french email address I get the following exception:

> an invalid character was found in the mail header: é

My questions are :

- Is it possible to use c# to send an email to an address containing french accented characters?.
- If yes, then How?

Comment: Have you tried URLencoding the characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Url encoding of the french character `é` is

```
%E9
```

You can use:

```
HttpUtility.UrlEncode("é", System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1"))
```

Which gives the correct encoded output: `%E9`

Comment: just be careful to only encode the username and not the @ sign nor the domain.